# Spring Boot 3 Webflux application with Micrometer Tracing not showing traceId and spanId in the console logs

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux, micrometer, micrometer-tracing

I'm replacing Spring Cloud Sleuth to generate log correlation with the new Micrometer Tracing for Spring Boot 3.

I've been following [this blog post](https://spring.io/blog/2022/10/12/observability-with-spring-boot-3) to configure a [sample project](https://github.com/codependent/demotracing)

The traceId/spanId don't seem to be automatically generated per request:

```
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    fun hello(): String {
        val currentSpan: Span? = tracer.currentSpan()
        logger.info("Hello!")
        return "hello"
    }
```

`currentSpan` is null and the log shows empty strings:

```
2022-11-28T14:53:05.335+01:00  INFO [server,,] 9176 --- [ctor-http-nio-2] d.DemotracingApplication$$SpringCGLIB$$0 : Hello!
```

This is my current config:

```
logging.pattern.level=%5p [${spring.application.name:},%X{traceId:-},%X{spanId:-}]
```

And the dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("io.micrometer:micrometer-tracing-bridge-brave")
    implementation("io.projectreactor.kotlin:reactor-kotlin-extensions")
    implementation("io.micrometer:micrometer-registry-prometheus")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-reactor")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("io.projectreactor:reactor-test")
}
```

Why isn't it working?

**EDIT:**

WebMVC applications aren't affected by this problem, and log the correlation information after upgrading.

There seems to be a change of behaviour for Webflux applications though. There's and [open issue about this](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33372).

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/33280

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently there's an even simpler solution placing `Hooks.enableAutomaticContextPropagation();` in your main method.

```
  public static void main(final String[] args) {
    Hooks.enableAutomaticContextPropagation();
    SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
  }
```

With that in place we don't have to do anything else to transparently propagate and log the tracing information in Webflux applications.

[Micrometer doc reference](https://micrometer.io/docs/observation#instrumentation_of_reactive_libraries)

Answer (score 2):

There are [several ways to achieve it](https://micrometer.io/docs/observation#instrumentation_of_reactive_libraries), the following excerpt shows two of them, `ContextSnapshot.setThreadLocalsFrom` and the `handle()` operator

```
    @GetMapping("/hello")
    fun hello(): Mono<String> {
        return Mono.deferContextual { contextView: ContextView ->
            ContextSnapshot.setThreadLocalsFrom(contextView, ObservationThreadLocalAccessor.KEY)
                .use { scope: ContextSnapshot.Scope ->
                    val traceId = tracer.currentSpan()!!.context().traceId()
                    logger.info("<ACCEPTANCE_TEST> <TRACE:{}> Hello!", traceId)
                    webClient.get().uri("http://localhost:7654/helloWc")
                        .retrieve()
                        .bodyToMono(String::class.java)
                        .handle { t: String, u: SynchronousSink<String> ->
                            logger.info("Retrieved helloWc {}", t)
                            u.next(t)
                        }
                }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Feel free to check my demo project [spring-cloud-gateway-upgrade](https://github.com/sandra-markerud/spring-cloud-gateway-upgrade) with branch 'spring-boot-3.x-upgrade' (based on [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77569821/spring-boot-3-x-with-micrometer-tracing-problems-for-spring-cloud-gateway)). It shows the additional setup needed to make tracing work for all wanted loggers (e.g. access-log)