# Spring Boot 3.x with Micrometer Tracing problems for spring-cloud-gateway

Tags: spring-webflux, spring-cloud-gateway, spring-cloud-sleuth, spring-boot-3, micrometer-tracing

We are trying to upgrade our spring-cloud-gateway from Spring Boot 2.7.18 with Sleuth and Brave to 3.1.5. with Micrometer Tracing and Brave.
So far so good.

In Spring Boot (Webflux) prior 3 we could use io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http-brave for adding spanIds and traceIds to HttpClient and HttpServer logs.
See: [ReactorNettyHttpTracing (deprecated) equivalent in Micrometer Tracing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75046362/reactornettyhttptracing-deprecated-equivalent-in-micrometer-tracing)

This approach does not work anymore with micrometer tracing.

We are facing multiple issues:

- Requests logs from the HttpClient and HttpServer do not contain traceIds or spanIds anymore
- The Netty access log also does not contain traceIds or spanIds anymore

I created a sample project to demonstrate the issues with JUnit Tests:
https://github.com/sandra-markerud/spring-cloud-gateway-upgrade
The 'master' branch contains the spring boot 2x version
The 'feature/upgrade' branch contains the spring boot 3.1.5 version

Any help would be highly appreciated.

What have I done so far:

Setup according to documentation:

- https://github.com/micrometer-metrics/tracing/wiki/Spring-Cloud-Sleuth-3.1-Migration-Guide
- [Spring Boot v3.1.0 Webflux Micrometer Tracing Logging Trace and Span IDs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76409733/spring-boot-v3-1-0-webflux-micrometer-tracing-logging-trace-and-span-ids)

So far, only the following features work:

- logging of traceId and spanId within "normal" log statements within the application
- b3 tracing headers are sent in requests to downstream services

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, due to the findings and fixes in [#2850](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/2850), [#3003](https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/issues/3003) and [spring-boot-3-tracing-coroutine](https://github.com/grassehh/spring-boot-3-tracing-coroutine) I could finally piece together a working sample:

[spring-cloud-gateway-upgrade](https://github.com/sandra-markerud/spring-cloud-gateway-upgrade) with branch 'spring-boot-3.x-upgrade' contains a spring-cloud-gateway in version spring-boot-3-2-1 with logbook 3.7.2.

The tests show that logging and tracing now finally work correctly depending on logbook being enabled or disabled.

I hope this helps other people that struggle with the same problems :)